# VFP9 : Removing a control from a Grid Column

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have added an extra TextBox control to a column of a grid, and I want to remove that extra control.  The guidance I have seen suggests finding the control in the property sheet (which I *can* do) and then clicking on the form's caption area and pressing 'Delete'.

I must be doing something wrong!  I have clicked on the control in the properties window so that it is highlighted (blue).  Pressing delete does not do anything.  If I right-click on this entry (in the properties window), a menu is indeed displayed (beginning 'Property Descriptions'), but there is no 'Delete'.  I have also tried pressing Ctrl-X while the control is highlighted in the properties window, but without success.

Would be grateful for guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Ctrl+Click on the grid (puts grid in edit mode).
- Click the column where the unwanted textbox contol is. In PEM sheet
  you would see the column's name - say Column3.
- In PEM Sheet click the drop down and select the textbox under that
  column. Now in PEM sheet you should see the name of the textbox.
- Click the form title and then DEL.

It is really simple.

Comment: Thank you Cetin.  Yes, that works.  I had selected the control on the PEM sheet, and had then optimistically tried right-clicking on that control to bring up a menu (to include 'Delete').  What you have to do is to leave the PEM sheet (with that control highlighted), and then click on the caption of the form and press Delete (as you mention).  This does not delete the caption (or indeed the form), but deletes the currently selected control in the PEM window.  It is not intuitive, but it works!.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is:

- Select the grid control
- Right-click and select the 'Properties...' option
- From the combobox in the property window select the column with the control you want to remove
- Select the control you want to remove

[image]

- Click on the grid control and then press 'DEL'

It is a little bit tricky.

Comment: Thank you Ciccio.  Yes that works;  as you say, it is a bit tricky  - having selected the control in the PEM window, you have to click somewhere on the form (I click on the caption, but your suggestion is better)  - and then clicking on 'Delete' has the desired effected on the currently selected control in the PEM window.  Not intuitive, but I will try to remember that technique!